# How to have static trait from_str method return trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm still very new to Rust and am trying to get my head around the differences between Java interfaces and Rust traits. The example below is trying to model the way I'd do things in Java, which may not be the idiomatic way in Rust.

I have a trait where I would like to return some implementation of the trait/interface by calling a `from_str()` method:

```
pub trait Ast: Display + Debug {
    fn from_str(dot_str: &str) -> Result<Box<Self>, AstParseError>;
    // some other methods applicable to Ast
}
```

Now here is an implementation of the trait (assume struct `AstParseError` exists):

```
pub struct DotAst {}

impl Ast for DotAst {
    fn from_str(str: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn Ast>, AstParseError> {
        // ...
        // now return a boxed version of my Ast implementation
        Ok(Box::new(DotAst::new()))

    }
}
```

I get an error "the trait `Ast` cannot be made into an object E0038". What should the signature of my DotAst `from_string()` implementation look like? Is this even possible in Rust, or should I be following a different pattern entirely.  The motivation is that I want to have many types of Ast, where I'd like to call `from_str()` on a specific implementation and receive the generic object back.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to append `where Self: Sized` to the method declaration to make the function "explicitly non-dispatchable": https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety.

```rust
pub trait Ast: Debug + Display {
    fn from_str(dot_str: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn Ast>, AstParseError> where Self: Sized;
}
```

Comment: What does "explicitly non-dispatchable" mean in practice please?

Comment: You explicitly say "I don't need this method on trait, ignore it when creating `dyn Ast`".

Comment: @John I guess it means *not virtual*. For dynamic dispatch to take place, we need a fat pointer (addr+vtable) like `&self` or `&mut self`.

Comment: There's a definition of dispatchable/explicitly non-dispatchable at that link, but yes it comes down to having access to the vtable via a fat pointer.

Comment: You also need the trait method to return `Box<dyn Ast>`, not `Box<Self>`.